If $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard Normal random variable, what is the distribution of $\Phi(X)$?
Let $\Phi$ be the cumulative distribution function of a standard Normal random variable, $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Let $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ follow any Normal distribution. We know that $\Phi(Z)\sim \operatorname{UNIF}(0,1)$, the standard uniform distribution. What distribution does $\Phi(X)$ follow?

Not a named one, but you can derive its CDF.

CDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x]  $\frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\mu -x}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)$

Is it me or the question is confusing? What is that uniform distribution?

Since $\ \Phi\ $ is strictly increasing, it has a strictly increasing inverse $\ \Phi^{-1}:(0,1)\rightarrow(-\infty,\infty)\ .$ Then, for $\ 0<x<1\ ,$
\begin{align}
P(\Phi(X)\le x)&=P\big(X\le \Phi^{-1}(x)\big)\\
&=P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le\frac{\Phi^{-1}(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\\
&=\Phi\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(x)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\ ,
\end{align}
with $\ P(\Phi(X)\le x)=0\ $ for $\ x\le0\ $ and $\ P(\Phi(X)\le x)=1\ $ for $\ 1\le x\ .$
